# how to avoid overwriting nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :balance_sheets
end
```

and

```
class BalanceSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
end
```

When I perform an UPDATE sending `"balance_sheet"=>{"activity_ids"=>["10", "20"]}` if I have previous activities loaded on the balance_sheet object, the activities collection is replaced. **I don't want override the activities old values, I want to add new ones**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the BalanceSheet object directly. Instead, create an intermediate BalanceSheetUpdater class which will take your `activity_ids` and append it to the existing `balance_sheet`'s `activity_ids`.

```
class BalanceSheetUpdater
  def initialize balance_sheet
    @balance_sheet = balance_sheet
  end

  def call(balance_sheet_params)
    new_ids = balance_sheet_params.delete("activity_ids")
    update_status = @balance_sheet.update(balance_sheet_params)

    if update_status
      existing_ids = @balance_sheet.activity_ids
      @balance_sheet.update(existing_ids + new_ids)
    end

    update_status
  end
end

# controller
updater = BalanceSheetUpdater.new(@balance_sheet)
if updater.call(balance_sheet_params)
  ... # success / fail actions
```